# Python MergeSort

Tags: python, list, mergesort, pseudocode

I am trying to implement a Python merge sort, But I am failing in some points. the pseudo code I have is accurate but looks like it was built for a different language.

The pseudo requires the following
/declare array temp of size of input array a

I am not sure how this is possible in Python. Anyway, the code is below.
The whole idea is that I need to sort the array/list and return the sorted one.

As of now, it's failing with the following message. I would say that this is because of the new temp array/list, but I am not sure

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "./mergesort", line 56, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "./mergesort", line 52, in main  
    mergesortbase(array)  
  File "./mergesort", line 4, in mergesortbase  
    mergesort(num, 0, len(num)-1)  
  File "./mergesort", line 10, in mergesort  
    mergesort(num, low, mid)  
  File "./mergesort", line 10, in mergesort  
    mergesort(num, low, mid)  
  File "./mergesort", line 12, in mergesort  
    merge(num, low, mid, mid+1, high)  
  File "./mergesort", line 27, in merge  
    temp[k] = a[j]  
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Note: a total revamp of the code is not helping, as I will need to use that exact pseudo code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

def mergesortbase(num):
    mergesort(num, 0, len(num)-1)


def mergesort(num, low, high):
    if low < high:
      mid = (low + high) // 2
      mergesort(num, low, mid)
      mergesort(num, mid+1, high)
      merge(num, low, mid, mid+1, high)

def merge(a, l1, u1, l2, u2):
# declare array temp of size of input array a
# Comment -- Not doable in Python to create array/list with specific size
    temp = []
    i = l1
    j = l2
    k = l1

    while (i <= u1 and j <= u2):
      if (a[i] <= a[j]):
         temp[k] = a[i]
         i = i + 1
      else:
         temp[k] = a[j]
         j = j + 1

      k = k + 1

    while ( i <= u2 ):
       temp[k] = a[i]
       k = k + 1
       i = i + 1

    while ( j <= u2 ):
       temp[k] = a[j]
       k = k + 1
       i = i + 1

    h = l1

    while ( h <= u2 ):
       a[h] = temp[h]
       h = h + 1


def main():
   array = [8, 5, 7, 1, 9, 3]
   mergesortbase(array)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: "Comment -- Not doable in Python to create array/list with specific size" of course you can create a list in python with a specific size. In this case, you can just use `.append` though, which would be more Pythonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors in your code

1. temp is not initialized to any size so k always give `list assignment index out of range`
2. Second  while loop for adding the remaining elements l1 to u1 needs to run only till u1 not u2:
3. Third while loop for adding the remaining elements from l2 to u2 need to increment `j` rather than `i`.

   ```
   def merge(a, l1, u1, l2, u2):
       temp = [0]*len(a)
       i = l1
       j = l2
       k = l1
       while (i <= u1 and j <= u2):
           if (a[i] <= a[j]):
               temp[k] = a[i]
               i = i + 1
           else:
               temp[k] = a[j]
               j = j + 1

           k = k + 1
       while ( i <= u1 ):
           temp[k] = a[i]
           k = k + 1
           i = i + 1
       while ( j <= u2 ):
           temp[k] = a[j]
           k = k + 1
           j = j + 1

       h = l1

       while ( h <= u2 ):  
           a[h] = temp[h]
           h = h + 1
   ```

Comment: how to return the final sorted array from that ?

Comment: @Wael array `a` is already sorted, you can directly `print(a)` in the `main` function

Comment: I am not sure what to say, YOU ARE AMAZINGGGGGGGGG, thank you for the help. I accepted your answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious as to why you don't just use Python's built-in sort stuff, either `sort` or `sorted` depending on your needs. It's likely to be more efficient than something you roll yourself (unless you use specific extra information on the data set, which doesn't seem to be the case here). It *may* be that you're doing this for educational purposes, in which case feel free to ignore this paragaph, but I'd be remiss in not mentioning the built-in stuff if your intent is just to sort some data.

In any case, your specific question seems to be how to "declare array temp of size of input array a".

That's easily done with the statement:

```
temp = [0] * len(a)
```

The following transcript shows this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> temp = [0] * len(a)
>>> temp
[0, 0, 0]
```

---

What you have at the moment is:

```
temp = []
```

which creates a list of size zero, followed by:

```
temp[k] = a[i]
```

That's always going to cause a problem since there's no value of `k` for which that will work.

---

On top of that, your actual merge is flawed in that you're using incorrect variables to process the arrays. You have quite logically tied certain items together such as `i` with the first array section, and `j` with the second, but then you violate that later on:

```
while ( i <= u2 ):  # i and u1 should be associated: while i <= u1:
   temp[k] = a[i]   # (no need for '()' in Python conditions by the way).
   k = k + 1
   i = i + 1

while ( j <= u2 ):
   temp[k] = a[j]
   k = k + 1
   i = i + 1        # j and u2 should be associated: j = j + 1
```

Even once you fix the array creation, it's likely that the second loop above will cause an issue. It will run for eternity (or until exception, whichever comes first) because you're checking `j` but never changing it. However, *both* items above are incorrect so should be fixed.

Once I make the array the correct size, make those two changes, and print out the array before and after sorting, it seems a little better:

```
[8, 5, 7, 1, 9, 3]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: @paxdiablo, k is assigned the value of l1, the value of l1 is the value of "low" from the function call " merge(num, low, mid, mid+1, high)"

Comment: @Wael, it doesn't really matter what value `k` has if you try to use it to index a zero-sized array. I suggest you fix the array first.

Comment: "That's easily done with the statement:" to be pedantic, it isn't easily done in Python, because *Python doens't have variable declarations*. Of course, pseudcode should probably not refer to something like a "declaration", and of course, we all understand what it means in this context... but still

Comment: @paxdiablo , I copied the list with "temp = a.copy()", but still failing, very hard to trace why its still failing, But anyway, this is what  I changed.
 temp =  a.copy(). The error message is IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @Wael, see the update, it explains where your code is going off the rails.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just make copy of input array?

temp = a.copy()

It will be same size.

If you want to initialize to some value all of the elements in temp, use something like:

temp = [0] * len(a)